# Rails: display message instantly on the view once send

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used **acts-as-messageable gem** for messaging system.
What i want is how can we immediately display a message, the count of new messages to another user once the message is sent on the browser.

According to my current implementation i have to reload the page to display the message.
what i know is to set an interval of say 30 seconds and then append the sent messages and update the count.So, how can we make it instant?

Any solution/reference/steps will be really helpful?

Comment: Don't really know `act_as_messagable` but it sounds like you might need to using polling. Or check in with the server every so often to see if any new messages are available.

Comment: which version of rails? IF 4, can look look at streaming.  Or perhaps some other websocket type implementations.

Comment: my rails version is 3.2.13